# Does KNN need training?

Tags: python, knn

The concept of KNN is to find the nearest data points to the required data.

therefore there is no math or processes before testing the model.

all it does is finding closest K points which mean no training process.

if this is right, then what happens in the training process for KNN in python??

```
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier  
classifier = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=5)  
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Then something happen in the background when fit gets called.

What is that happening if the process requires no calculations

Comment: Not exactly a programming question.. See
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/349842/why-do-we-need-to-fit-a-k-nearest-neighbors-classifier for an answer!

Comment: isn't python a programming language?!

Comment: @asmgx it is. but this question is not specific to python. Rather it is a general math problem, right?

Comment: @asmgx The question does not seem to relate to Python though. Maybe you could specify what you mean by "the training process for KNN in python". Are you using scikit-learn, or something else?

Comment: If it requires no calculations why are you using a computer for it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

KNN is not quite a specific algorithm on itself, but rather a method that you can implement in several ways. The idea behind [nearest neighbors](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/neighbors.html) is to select one or more examples from the training data to decide the predicted value for the sample at hand. The simplest way to do that is to simply iterate through the whole dataset and pick the closest data points from the training dataset. In that case, you could skip the fitting step, or you could see the fitting as the production of a callable function that runs that loop. Even in that case, is you are using a library like [scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org), it is useful to maintain a similar interface to all predictors, so you can write generic code for them (e.g. training code independent from the specific algorithm used).

However, you can do smarter things for KNN too. In scikit-learn, you will see that [`KNeighborsClassifier`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.html) implements three different algorithms. One is brute force, which is just traversing the whole dataset as described, but you also have [`BallTree`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.BallTree.html) ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ball_tree)) and [`KDTree`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KDTree.html) ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree)). These are data structures that can accelerate the search for nearest neighbors, but they need to be constructed in advance from the data. So the fitting step here is building the data structure that will help you find the nearest neighbors.

Comment: Thanks, You mean that KNN by itself does not require training (fitting), but the training is for other methods such as KDTree to speed the prediction process, right?

Comment: @asmgx Depends on what you mean by "KNN by itself". Using a KDTree here is not "other method" it is a possible implementation of KNN. As I said, KNN as a method does not strictly specify how the nearest neighbors are found. So, if your version of KNN uses a KDTree, then building the KDTree is an integral part of using the method. But you can interpret each thing as you prefer. As I said, conceptually every machine learning model requires some "fitting", and that can be a very complex algorithm or just storing the data for later querying.